# Need to know how to sum int

Tags: c#, arrays, sum

```
int con_male_g1 = Convert.ToInt32(male_g1_per);
int con_male_g2 = Convert.ToInt32(male_g2_per);
int con_male_g3 = Convert.ToInt32(male_g3_per);
int con_male_g4 = Convert.ToInt32(male_g4_per);
int con_male_g5 = Convert.ToInt32(male_g5_per);
int con_male_g6 = Convert.ToInt32(male_g6_per);
```

I want to know how to sum value all of the int?

Comment: con_male_g1  + con_male_g2  + con_male_g3 and so on

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. If you just want to simply sum all numbers in current condition, just `int sum = con_male_g1+con_male_g2+con_male_g3+con_male_g4+con_male_g5+con_male_g6;`.
2. If you store those numbers in one List or Array, like

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(Convert.ToInt32(male_g1_per));
list.Add(Convert.ToInt32(male_g2_per));
...
```

, you can get the sum value by just `int sum = list.Sum();`(using System.Linq is needed)

3. If that `male_g1_per` was the value from some array or list like `List<string>` at the very beginning, you also can

```
int sum = stringList.Sum((x) => Convert.ToInt32(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

Linq approach

```
string[] input = { male_g1_per, male_g2_per, male_g3_per, male_g4_per, male_g5_per};
int sum = input.Select(int.Parse).Sum();
```